# Scala Generics: Representing the Absence of a Type

Tags: scala, generics, events

I've created an event trait in Scala, which looks something like the following:

```
trait Event[A]
{
    def addListener(f: A=>Unit): Unit
    def rmvListener(f: A=>Unit): Unit
}
```

It works as anticipated for all types `A`, with one exception: `Event[Unit]` requires that the callbacks have type `(Unit)=>Unit` instead of `()=>Unit` as desired. Similarly, `Event[Nothing]` requires that the callbacks have type `(Nothing)=>Unit`. I've tried extending `Event[]` but it does not compile.

I'm hoping to avoid the need to  write `event.addListener((Unit)=>{ /*logic*/ }`.

Possibly the simplest solution is to write a second trait `Action` with `f: ()=>Unit`, but I'm hoping to the avoid duplicating the event system logic.

Does anyone know of a good way to represent the absence of a type while using generics in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a good way to represent the absence of a type while using generics in Scala?

There isn't one. But

> I'm hoping to avoid the need to write `event.addListener((Unit)=>{ /*logic*/ }`.

You don't need to; you would write `event.addListener { _ => /*logic*/ }` or `event.addListener { case () => /*logic*/ }` (note that in the second case `{}` instead of `()` is required).

> Possibly the simplest solution is to write a second trait Action with f: ()=>Unit, but I'm hoping to the avoid duplicating the event system logic.

You could write it like

```
trait Action extends Event[Unit] {
  // calls Event.addListener
  def addListener(f: () => Unit) = addListener(_ => f())
}
```